# Why does this code goes into infinite loop? - python

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop

i tried to when year and month match loop end but it not works, how i get rid of infinite loop

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)

month = "March"
year = 2023

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='datepicker']").click()


while True:
    mon = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ui-datepicker-month']").text
    yr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ui-datepicker-year']").text
    print(mon, yr)
    if mon == month and yr == year:
        break
    else:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/a[2]/span").click()
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: `yr` is probably an `str` not an `int`. So the loop never breaks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is going to be a string vs integer comparison issue. `"2023"` is not the same as `2023` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try using equals or is:

```
mon.__eq__(month) and yr.__eq__(year)
```

Instead of while true you can also negate the part that you use for breaking so it will be like while year and month not equal to something do this.